# Getting the selected radio without using "Id" but "name"

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I was trying to get selected radio button by using "document.getElementByName('nameOfradio')" because all of the radio buttons share the same name. But, nothing happened. I tried the same thing with document.getElementById('nameOfradio') and worked well.However, I had to give unique id for all of the radio buttons. So that, it turns ugly when i have 20 radio buttons. As a result, what I wanted is making a shortcut. How can i get the value of selected radio button by using their "name"? Codes;

**Html**

```
<input type="radio" name="nameOfradio" value="onm1" /> 1
<input type="radio" name="nameOfradio" value="onm2" /> 2

<input type='button' onclick='radio3()' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

**Ajax(relavant part of radio3())**

```
var radioPushed = document.getElementByName('nameOfradio').value;

var queryString = "?radioPushed=" + radioPushed;//to send the value to another file
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "radio_display.php" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

As i said document.getElementById worked but it requires too much work:( How can i make it simplier by using common feature of radio buttons, instead of giving them unique id? A short explanation why i could not make it would be very helpful(new in javascript and ajax)

Comment: `document.getElementByName()` is not a function in JavaScript. Typo? "Element" should be plural.

Comment: document.getElementsByName() would be the closest valid one.

Answer (score 41):

This line:

```
document.getElementByName('nameOfradio').value
```

should be:

```
 document.querySelector('input[name=nameOfradio]:checked').value;
```

using [**querySelector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Note that CSS pseudo-classes are accessed by a colon (:).

Answer (score 5):

```
document.querySelector('input[name=nameOfRadio]:checked').value
```

Eg:-

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other  
</form> 

document.querySelector('input[name=gender]:checked').value
```

Also, you can add a `checked` attribute to a default radio button among the group of radio buttons if needed

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
```

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself some pain in the later js dev and use a js library like jQuery. Then you can do something like `$('input[name=radioName]:checked').val()`

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why you should use a javascript library.

```
document.querySelector('input[name=nameOfradio]');
```

for example is not supported before IE8.

Let the library handle the browser craziness.

In jQuery you can just use `$('input[name=radioName]:checked').val()` or `$("form").serialize()` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `class` property if your looking for a quick solution. Many elements can have the same `class`. use the command:

```
document.getElementsByClass('nameOfradio');
```

In addition you should use the correct form of getting elements by name which is:

```
document.getElementsByName('nameOfradio');
```

You can also use the following code to find the selected radio value as follows:

```
radioObj=document.getElementsById('nameOfradio');
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined) {
    if(radioObj.checked) {
        return radioObj.value;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) {
        return radioObj[i].value;
    }
}
return "";
```

Comment: He still needs to figure out what one is selected.