# How do I change paragraph text using JavaScript, depending on which radio button is checked in a form?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, paragraph

What I´m trying to achieve is to have 1 question with 4 possible answers to choose from (radio buttons). When the user presses the button after the form, I want a paragraph to tell them more about the choice they made.

I´ve targeted the button, the paragraph and the radio buttons in my JavaScript. I´ve also managed to make the paragraph text appear whenever I choose the first radio button. However, I only want the text in the paragraph to appear if both one radio button has been chosen AND the button has been pressed. I want different content to appear in the paragraph depending on which radio button has been chosen.

Any tips or solutions would be greatly appreciated =)

Here is my code so far:

```html
<form action="">
  <h1>A friend invites you to a party. You...</h1>
  <br />

  <input id="red" type="radio" name="color" value="red">...bluntly tell your friend you have other priorities. <br/>
  <input id="blue" type="radio" name="color" value="blue">...tell your friend you are finishing a coding assignment tonight. <br/>
  <input id="yellow" type="radio" name="color" value="yellow">...hug your friend and start discussing the outfit. <br/>
  <input id="green" type="radio" name="color" value="green">...thank your friend for inviting you, and tell her you look forward to it. <br/>

</form>

<button> Click me </button>

<p></p>

<script>
  let btn = document.querySelector('button');
  let para = document.querySelector('p');
  let response = document.querySelector('input');

  response.addEventListener('change', myColor);

  function myColor() {
    let choice = response.value;
    if (choice === 'red') {
      para.textContent = 'You´re so red!';
    } else if (choice === 'blue') {
      para.textContent = 'You´re so blue!';
    } else if (choice === 'yellow') {
      para.textContent = 'You´re so yellow!';
    } else if (choice === 'green') {
      para.textContent = 'You´re so green!';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. You only want the relevant text to appear when "click me" is pressed? Then you need to attach your function to a `click` event on the button - not, as you are now, to a `change` event on the radio input.

Comment: Hi Robin, you´re right. I should have specified that more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the `form` you wrapped to [get the **selected** radio value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) and check against it.

Like this:

```html
<form action="">
  <h1>A friend invites you to a party. You...</h1>
  <br />

  <input id="red" type="radio" name="color" value="red">...bluntly tell your friend you have other priorities. <br/>
  <input id="blue" type="radio" name="color" value="blue">...tell your friend you are finishing a coding assignment tonight. <br/>
  <input id="yellow" type="radio" name="color" value="yellow">...hug your friend and start discussing the outfit. <br/>
  <input id="green" type="radio" name="color" value="green">...thank your friend for inviting you, and tell her you look forward to it. <br/>

</form>

<button> Click me </button>

<p></p>

<script>
  const form = document.querySelector('form');
  let btn = document.querySelector('button');
  let para = document.querySelector('p');
  let response = document.querySelector('input');

  //response.addEventListener('change', myColor);
  btn.addEventListener('click', myColor);

  function myColor() {
    let choice = form.color.value;
    if (!choice) {
      return;
    } 
    if (choice === 'red') {
      para.textContent = 'You´re so red!';
    } else if (choice === 'blue') {
      para.textContent = 'You´re so blue!';
    } else if (choice === 'yellow') {
      para.textContent = 'You´re so yellow!';
    } else if (choice === 'green') {
      para.textContent = 'You´re so green!';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i never thought to o beyond the `querySelector('input[name=color]:checked` way and have not used the form for quite some yaers. Completely dropped from my mind :-)

Comment: Sure. The oldies is the goodies :) If it answer your question, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so it will help to other people. And best of luck :)

Comment: Would do so, but aint the one who asked :-)

Comment: Glad to head :)

Answer (score 0):

1) When you define `let response = document.querySelector('input');`, you need to realize that [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only gives you one matching HTML element. This explains why only your first radio button does anything.

2) If you want anything to happen when you click the button, just add an onclick-handle to the button (`button.addEventListener('click', myColor);`).

3) to find the selected value in a set of radio buttons, you need to take a small detour - try like this (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275597/getting-the-selected-radio-without-using-id-but-name)): 
    let choice = document.querySelector('input[name=color]:checked');
    choice = choice && choice.value;
The first line finds the selected radio button of name `color`. Be aware: this will be `null` if no radio has been selected. The second line replaces the variable's value by the radios value, if it was not `null`. Otherwise, it will still be null, so you can check for `} else if (choice === null) {` and set some text asking the user to select a color before pressing the button.

I hope this was clear enough and helps you out!
Regards,
Simon

Comment: As Mosh Feu pointed out in his answer, for point 3 you can more easily use the browsers built in `from` properties (namely this one) to query the selected value with `let choice = document.forms[0].color.value;`. Rest stays the same

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice and clarification Beppo! I really appreciate all the help here on this forum. I will definitely try out your suggestion in point 3). Lots to learn. Hopefully I will be able to give some support back to this forum when I get better. So far all the questions seem really hard to me =)